# Using 'echo' in a bash script to write to serial port

Tags: bash, shell, serial-port

I am trying to port a script to handle 'writing to a serial port' from matlab.
I have a serial device on the port /dev/ttyUSB0, to which I need to write '\xFE\x6C\x01' to turn on a relay.
I used

```
echo -en '\xFE\x6C\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

on the terminal. It works fine and the relay is turned on.
Now if i use it in a bash script file,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en '\xFE\x6C\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and run the file, nothing happens. Why is it so?

This is my first serious bash script. Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? Does running `bash -x script.sh` show the echo happening? Are you running the script as a user that can write to that device?

Comment: Is that the whole of your bash script file?

Comment: Okay, I look like an idiot now. I ran the script with `sh script.sh`. and with `sh -x script.sh` (The latter showed the echo happening, but still the serial relay wasn't turned on.) If I run `bash -x script.sh` the relay turns on. What is the difference? (Thanks a lot)
I removed everything else from my bash script for the sake of clarity

Comment: `sh`'s builtin `echo` doesn't support the `-e` option. Maybe that explains why you don't get what you want when the script is executed with `sh`. With `sh`, you may use the _external_ `echo` command, with `/bin/echo`.

Comment: @chinn `sh` is most commonly `dash`, not `bash`. And, as the above comment points out, `echo` in `bash` is a builtin, so the results are not necessarily going to be portable. That's one of the reasons why using [printf is preferred if you're trying to do anything more fancy than just printing a basic string](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/60101). (`printf` is also a builtin in bash, but is far more portable except in various extension cases)

Comment: I ran `/bin/echo -en '\xFE\x6C\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0` from command line. The relay turns on. So I rewrote the script to `#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo -en '\xFE\x6C\x01' > /dev/ttyUSB0` and now it works with `sh`  too. Thanks for pointing out the difference.
I can mark this as an answer if posted as one.

Comment: Also, with `sh`'s `echo` you can use `echo -n '\0376\0154\0001'`.

Comment: Or rather, the POSIX specification for `echo` states that escape sequences be processed. The `-e` option to `bash`'s `echo` simply enables POSIX behavior. As BroSlow says, use `printf` instead for consistent behavior.

Answer (score -1):

I think that is not possible, because with a simple `echo`, it is not possible to set a speed of serial port.

Comment: Can you share how to set the speed of a serial port?

Comment: @Kyle Hotchkiss For example with perl using Device::SerialPort you can set port speed with:                                                                                                            my $s = new Device::SerialPort("/dev/ttySXXXX");            $s->baudrate(9600);                                                                  $s->write("hello world");